# Probing server in Mozilla Thunderbird won't finish

Tags: email, thunderbird, ssl

I am trying to configure an e-mail account in Mozilla Firefox that some months ago used to work.

However, when I try to configure it, it will stop when "Probing server", it keeps forever probing the server.

[image]

I guess this has something to do with the SSL certificate according to my Internet research, but I didn't find a solution for this.

The e-mail account is created from CPanel in a hosting24.com paid account.

Thanks!

Comment: I exactly have same issue. Difference is i don't use cpanel. I connect my account with Android and some other clients (like claws). Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, this is how I solved the problem.

Add the email account without SSL, make sure to select normal password, and select NO SECURITY.
Then go to account settings, and change it to the SSL settings.

The security certificate will then show up, and that will allow you to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a faster way:

In the same Mail Account Setup window, set both Port fields as **auto**.

Edit from my comment: In the Mail Account Setup window (the very same one that was posted by the OP up there) there's a Port option for both Incoming and Outcoming rows. Click on the drop-down lists and select the **auto** option for both rows.

Comment: Can you expand upon this answer?

Comment: In the Mail Account Setup window (the very same one that was posted by the OP up there) there's a Port option for both Incoming and Outcoming rows.  Click on the drop-down lists and select the **auto** option for both rows.